# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis React-native realm database

Tags: android, database, react-native, realm

When I try to use `realm` with `react-native`, Its' works in iOS but in android, I'm facing the below error.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis
```

[image]

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
"realm": "^10.12.0"
```

Comment: How does what's shown in the question 'work' in iOS? Not sure I understand the correlation to the Swift code you'd use on that platform. Also, what is that code supposed to do? Are you missing a space or a {?

Comment: have you solved this issue? i'm also getting same issue in react native 0.67.2

Comment: Yes, it's fixed, just upgrade android jsc-android version.

Comment: i have upgraded to latest jsc-android,but still having issue

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `jsc-android` library version to the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check this

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/4350#issuecomment-1041592665

May be it's helping you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).